# UI from Livecode is not the Same as on Android

Tags: android, user-interface, text, livecode

I created a livecode project. I designed my UI by changing colors and fonts.
After creating that app, I deploy it to an android installer file (.apk file). When I launch the application to my android device, the UI from android device is not exactly the same as in the livecode. The text from the labels and buttons are getting too close which is annoying.

[image: A comparison (Livecode screenshot (left), Android screenshot (right))]

Comment: is your font bold? does this also happen in regular font?

Comment: My font is not bold.I tried to edit my app with two fields. One with bold font and the other one had regular font. When I viewed to my Android device, the bold field displays fine while the regular is not fine. @JeanLuc

Comment: ok, that's funny, because we have the same issue with Unity 4.6 new UI system on Android, but the other way around and haven't a proper solution yet. something with android's dynamic font rendering seems to be broken :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not including a font in your APK file, chances are that Android chooses a font different from the font chosen by iOS. Either set the textFont of the field to a font that is available on both platforms or include your own font. If you include a font with the standalone and make sure that it is located next to the engine file, the font will be available. You can check that a font is available by using the fontNames:

```
put ("Font Name" is among the lines of the fontNames) into myFontAvailable
```

The default textFont of a field is empty, which means that it is inherited from the stack. If the textFont of a stack is empty, the system font is used. On Windows, the system font is Segoe UI, on Mac OS X it is a different font. On Android and iOS, the system font is different again. If you want the font to be the same on all platforms, you have to set the textFont of the stack (or field) to a font name that is available on all platforms or include your own font.

Comment: I set my field with default font name.
What is the default font name? I seen blank font name from the property inspector.

Comment: I have added explanations to the answer.